# switching wpf resource dictionaries at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am trying to build a wpf application that allows the user to change the theme at runtime.  What I have done so far is create a resourcedictionary with all the colors for the application defined in it and then I am binding to this dictionary in the xaml.

Below is the code I have for switching the resource dictionary:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
{
   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
   {
      ResourceDictionary dic = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(fs);
      Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
      Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dic);
   }
}
```

This code runs fine, and I know that it is switching the resource dictionary, but it does not update elements already displayed on the screen.  My question is: how can I refresh or rebind the screen to take into account the new resource dictionary?

thanks

sm

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I simply had to change:

```
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dic);
```

to:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dic);
```